# PHP Email Piping "can't exec" error

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I'm working on an app that needs to pipe an email to a php script that will read the inbound email and handle it according to the content. I've got the folder and script set to chmod 755 as required, and the default catch-all email for the domain is piping to the script. Here's the basic test script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
// ^ yes, that's the proper path to php
// read the email
$email = "";
$fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $email .= fread($fp, 1024);
}
fclose($fp);

// for testing put the email into a file on the server.
$t = microtime(true);
file_put_contents('/home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/THEDOMAIN.com/pipe/email-' . $t . '.txt', $email);

// email me a copy of the inbound email
$email = wordwrap($email, 70, "\r\n");
$to      = 'MYEMAIL@gmail.com';
$subject = 'You Sent a Test Email';
$headers = 'From: info@THEDOMAIN.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: info@THEDOMAIN.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
return mail($to, $subject, $email, $headers);
?>
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

pipe to |/home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/THEDOMAIN.com/pipe/send-test.php
generated by test@THEDOMAIN.com
local delivery failed

The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/THEDOMAIN.com/pipe/send-test.php
generated by test@THEDOMAIN.com ------

Could not exec '/home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/THEDOMAIN.com/pipe/send-test.php'

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;|/home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/THEDOMAIN.com/pipe/send-test.php
Status: 5.0.0
```

I've got other apps that are able to handle piped emails to scripts, so I'm at a loss as to what may be happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: Nope, not even a hint. Strangely enough, the odd email that comes into my acocunt fires off the piped function. No idea how

Answer (score 0):

check the File permissions (and directory of it) are set to 0755 and The file should be in ascii format and not binary

No whitespaces/newlines before/after the php tags and hashbang